# Chrome "Developer Tools" element - hide annoying yellow dimensions box

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How do I hide the annoying yellow box that appears under html fields when I hover over elements in the Chrome "Developer Tools" elements panel - it's driving me nuts as I can't see the bottom of my labels etc...

[image: See example image]

Comment: This is one is terribly annoying indeed

Comment: @MeLight - yeah it sure is - it's ok most of the time but when you're trying to sort out css margins etc it can be a real pain.

Comment: You can't hide it, file a bug on http://crbug.com and get people to star it.

Comment: here's the bug report http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=89510

Comment: Here's the new bug report: [Issue 282493: Inspector tooltip covers content (Issue 89510 was not fixed but was closed)](http://crbug.com/282493)

Comment: This is fixed in latest Chrome (Pressing Ctrl/Cmd when hovering elements in the console/DOM tree will inhibit the tooltip). 36.0.1978.0 (Developer Build 268656) - sweet :) https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=282493#c18

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check Chrome 16 which got an improved element tooltip. Please comment on the [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=89510)  and mention specific issues that you want to get fixed.

Answer (score 24):

From the posted bug: "https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=282493". If you hold keyboard Control (Ctrl) key before hovering the element (or command on a mac) the tooltip won't show. Not the ideal solution but it works as long as you know about it

Answer (score 3):

You can pretty easily tweak devtools yourself. Basically, follow [these](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/contributing.html) instructions to get started.

Then, inside `inspector.js`, tweak `WebInspector.highlightDOMNode`, by applying this small patch.

```
1150,1151c1150
<     // Do not highlight the DOM node.
<     //this.highlightDOMNodeForTwoSeconds(nodeId);
---
>     this.highlightDOMNodeForTwoSeconds(nodeId);
```

Fore more info, check out this post on [extending Chrome DevTools](http://smus.com/extending-chrome-developer-tools).

Comment: Thank you for sharing your article but it doesn't answer the question here. Can you be more specific on how to solve the problem?

Comment: The last paragraph of it's article contain a step by step explanation on how to remove this particular problem. @boris could you copy at least a summary or the relevant part of your blog post here ? (For a debate on Meta on copying versus linking to blog answers, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20531/how-to-refer-to-your-blog-when-answering )