# Chrome Web Inspector - CSS Panel on the Left

Tags: css, google-chrome, user-interface, customization, web-inspector

I've been looking into customising the Chrome Web Inspector ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149450/customise-the-look-of-the-chrome-web-inspector) and [here](http://darcyclarke.me/design/skin-your-chrome-inspector/) in particular) in an effort to move the CSS part of the Elements panel to the left, with the HTML on the right but I've had no joy.

Has anyone managed to get something like this working, or seen any examples of it?

Here's a quick hacked-up [screenshot](http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/2245/webinspector.png) of what I'm trying to get.

Edit: I'm using version `18.0.1025.33 beta-m` of Chrome, just in case there's any version-specific silliness :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't know you can style the web inspector in Chrome :P, here is some CSS that you can add to your `Custom.css` stylesheet found in your Chrome directory that will render the desired result:

```
Custom.css
```

---

```
#elements-content {
    left: 325px !important;
    right: 0 !important;
}

#elements-sidebar {
    left: 0 !important;
    right:auto !important;
    left:0 !important;
    border-right: 1px solid #404040 !important;
}

#elements-content[style] { /* to target the inline style */
   right:0 !important;
   left:325px !important;
}
```

From one of the links you provided, here are where the `Custom.css` stylesheet is located:

- Mac: ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User\
  StyleSheets/Custom.css
- PC: C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
  Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Custom.css
- Ubuntu (Chromium): ~/.config/chromium/Default/User\
  StyleSheets/Custom.css

Edit: screenshot

[image]

---

Here is a fixed version that should work on your version of Chrome, tried it on version 17.xxxx

**CSS**

```
#elements-content,
.scripts-views-container {
    left: 325px !important;
    right: 0 !important;
}

.split-view-sidebar-right  {
    float:right !important;
    right:auto !important;
    left:0 !important;
    width:325px !important;
}

.split-view-sidebar-left  {
    float:left !important;
    left:auto !important;
    right:0 !important;
}

.split-view-sidebar-left {
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(64%, 64%, 64%) !important;
}

.split-view-sidebar-left.maximized {
    border-left: none !important;
}

.split-view-sidebar-right {
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(64%, 64%, 64%) !important;
}

.split-view-sidebar-right.maximized {
    border-left: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Almost - http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/117/webinspectoralmost.png The elements panel is correct, but the styles are still hugging the right hand side like a teddy bear :/

Comment: @Joe what version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: 18.0.1025.33 beta-m - it just updated itself a couple of days ago, but it's running off the beta branch.

Comment: @Joe yeah, will test when i get home, i'm still rocking  Chrome 14 here at work for testing purposes, but looked at the latest css file used in the beta version and they changed all the classes. Just need to change the ids to point to the current classes being used to make it work.

Comment: Awesome, cheers. I couldn't find the right files when I had a dig around to try and find the classes, good job finding them :P Whereabouts are they? :)

Comment: @Joe you can dig around in the [trunk](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end) files of the web inspector, i'm searching around in the current [css](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end/inspector.css) and the [sidebarpane.js](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end/SidebarPane.js) file.

Comment: @Joe Updated my answer with a fixed version that should work with your version of Chrome.

Comment: I've just got back home, so I'll check it in the morning when I get back in :)

Comment: Works like a charm :) Cheers. Can't award the bounty for 3 hours, but it's on the way

Comment: Added an extra line to get the script panel too, but all working great :) Thanks a lot

Comment: @Joe Great, thansks o much, hope this helps future users as well.