# Hide Tooltips Chrome Developer Styles

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Does anyone know how to hide the html object tooltips in the Styles pane of Google Chrome Developer?

eg. when you click on a style to add a new attribute the yellow tooltip from the previous style element persists which covers over what you're trying to type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991260/chrome-developer-tools-element-hide-annoying-yellow-dimensions-box